# How to make a rich embed use the display color of a user discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm working on my user info command. It reacts to &userinfo {user ping/user ID}. If there are no args (no ID or ping), it shows the info about the executer of the command. I was wondering, how I could make the info embed have the same color as the display color of the user (so if my nick color is #0052ad, the embed color would also be #0052ad). The code I came up with so far is this:

```js
const { DiscordAPIError } = require('discord.js');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const moment = require('moment');

module.exports = {
 name: 'profile',
 description: 'The bot will return the info about the user',
 execute(message, args) {
  let userinfoget =
   message.mentions.members.first() ||
   message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) ||
   message.guild.member(message.author);

  var highestRoleID = userinfoget.roles.highest.id;
  console.log(`Highest role = ${highestRoleID}`);

  console.log(`User = ${userinfoget}`);

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setColor(message.guild.userinfoget.displayHexColor)
   .setAuthor(`${userinfoget.user.tag}`, userinfoget.user.displayAvatarURL())
   .addFields({ name: `User ping`, value: `<@${userinfoget.id}>` })
   .addFields({ name: `User ID`, value: `${userinfoget.id}` })
   .addFields(
    {
     name: 'Joined server',
     value: moment(userinfoget.joinedAt).format('LLLL'),
    } // or moment(userinfoget.joinedAt).format('DD/MM/YY, HH:mm:ss')
   )
   .addFields(
    {
     name: 'Joined Discord',
     value: moment(userinfoget.user.createdAt).format('LLLL'),
    } // or moment(userinfoget.createdAt).format('DD/MM/YY, HH:mm:ss')
   )
   .addFields({ name: 'Highest role', value: `<@&${highestRoleID}>` })
   .addFields({
    name: 'Online Status',
    value: `${userinfoget.presence.status}`,
   });
  message.channel.send(embed);
 },
};
```

but the bot crashes and the error is `Cannot read property 'displayHexColor' of undefined`. I also tried `.setColor(message.guild.userinfoget.displayHexColor)` as I saw on other posts, but that makes the embed the display color of the bot. What is the mistake I made? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means `message.guild.userinfoget` is undefined. You can remove `message.guild` from the beginning, as you already defined `userinfoget` as a `GuildMember`.

```js
userinfoget.displayHexColor
```

---

Also, you can shorten `message.guild.member(message.author)` to simply `message.member`, which will return the author as a `GuildMember`